# LEFT JOIN ALL results

Tags: mysql, join

Hello guys I  have a problem with a query and left join

I have 2 tables products and characteristics
I know some required characteristics with id 1,3,6

```
 SELECT * FROM products
    LEFT JOIN characteristics ...
    WHERE characteristics_id IN (1,2,6)
```

But this not works for me because I need the products with ALL of this characteristics, not only one.

**Really I need**

```
 SELECT * FROM products
    INNER JOIN characteristics as c1 ... AND c1.id=1
    INNER JOIN characteristics as c2 ... AND c2.id=2
    INNER JOIN characteristics as c2 ... AND c2.id=3
...
```

But it don't like me, there must be a simpler and efficient

Thank you.

Comment: What works and what does not? Could you explain what characteristics records you want?

Comment: can you add both the tables structure here so i can try it with the other fields

Comment: this not works because it query, list products with only one characteristic. I need to be list only the products with all characteristics, not only one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need a `LEFT JOIN` at all.

Second, your first attempt seems perfectly valid and I think it's the most efficient (when there are indexes on the tables to be joined). But I'm adding another way (that seems more simple as it has only 1 join).

---

**Simple** (to add more than 3 characteristics):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products AS p
  INNER JOIN characteristics AS c ON ...
WHERE c.id IN (1, 3, 6)
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING
  COUNT(*) = 3             --- or COUNT(DISTINCT c.id)
                           --- depending on your data
```

---

More **efficient** (in most cases, in other words: test, test and test again in your tables with various sizes and number of ids):

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM products AS p
  INNER JOIN characteristics AS c1 ON ... 
  INNER JOIN characteristics AS c2 ON ... 
  INNER JOIN characteristics AS c3 ON ... 
WHERE c1.id = 1 
  AND c2.id = 3 
  AND c3.id = 6
```

Comment: Ummmm - just put the extra criteria IN THE JOIN'S ON CLAUSE: join foo on <id match> and <other match>

Comment: @Bohemian: For `INNER JOIN`s, there is no difference in the execution plan (in all decent RDBMSs) whether you put the condition in the `ON` or the `WHERE` clause. I see it as more readable this way. But whatever works for you...

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could use a subselect and so something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
  products
WHERE
  (
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
    characteristics
  WHERE product = products.id AND characteristics_id IN (1,2,3)
  ) >= 3;
```

note that this isn't tested because you havn't posted your exact table-definitions.